# SSIS package fails when run as a job through SQL server

Tags: ssis

First time poster.

I have created an SSIS package that reads a text file and places the data in a table in SQL server.  When I run it in VS2005 it inserts the data into the table no problem.  If I run a job in SQL to call the SSIS package it fails and I get the attached error.

I am new to all this so my skills arent great but I am giving it a go!!  ( I have removed the server name and my login credentials from the error message)

error message

> Date,Source,Severity,Step ID,Server,Job Name,Step
>   Name,Notifications,Message,Duration,Sql Severity,Sql Message
>   ID,Operator Emailed,Operator Net sent,Operator Paged,Retries Attempted
>   05/21/2012
>   15:33:28,importsCallDataTest,Error,0,importsCallDataTest,(Job
>   outcome),,The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User   The last step
>   to run was step 1 (importsData).,00:00:01,0,0,,,,0 05/21/2012
>   15:33:28,importsCallDataTest,Error,1,,importsCallDataTest,importsData,,Executed
>   as user: \SYSTEM. ....00.4035.00 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  3:33:28 PM 
>   Progress: 2012-05-21 15:33:28.71     Source: Data Flow Task
>   Validating: 0% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-05-21
>   15:33:28.71     Source: Data Flow Task      Validating: 50% complete 
>   End Progress  Progress: 2012-05-21 15:33:28.84     Source: Data Flow
>   Task      Validating: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress:
>   2012-05-21 15:33:28.85     Source: Data Flow Task      Validating: 0%
>   complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-05-21 15:33:28.85     Source:
>   Data Flow Task      Validating: 50% complete  End Progress  Progress:
>   2012-05-21 15:33:28.87     Source: Data Flow Task      Validating:
>   100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-05-21 15:33:28.87
>   Source: Data Flow Task      Prepare for Execute: 0% complete  End
>   Progress  Progress: 2012-05-21 15:33:28.87     Source: Data Flow Task 
>   Prepare for ...  The package execution fa...  The step
>   failed.,00:00:01,0,0,,,,0

Comment: Have you considered the security aspects of whether sql can access the filesystem for the files you're importing?

Comment: I placed the ssis package on the C drive of the server and I believe it has the correct permissions

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server jobs are ran by the SQL Server Agent's account.

You have to check if this account has rights to access the file.

Comment: I can confirm that I have checked the permissions and they are correct.

Comment: where is the job that calls the package? same machine where the package works as a stand alone run?

Comment: I think your problem is at Executed as user: \SYSTEM. Can you post a print screen of the job step that calls the package?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of Package Creation you should Save the Credentials for Source and Destination Also .And at the time of Package Creation you have to login With Sql Server Agents Account .

Also Try:
--First Deploy the package and then Make Job Schedular .
--Create new CREDENTIAL and Proxy for SSIS package and use this proxy instead of sql server agent account.